# Halting problem confusion

Tags: computer-science

Does the non-solvability of the halting problem mean that no program can tell if an arbitrary program halts, or only that if such a program exists then there is no computable proof that it works?

Comment: Didn't know you were into computers, Jesus...

Comment: The first. There **is** no program such that $\dots$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A program that decides it (and works correctly for all input programs) cannot exist at all.

Or in other words, *every* program can be *proven* not to answer the halting problem correctly. Given a purported halting solver we can construct, through a diagonalization argument, an input program that the purported solver will give the wrong answer on.

Comment: Ok, but by 'proven' here, you mean in a formal system? And the diagonlization proof takes place within this formal system itself? Or do we need another formal system to diagonlize over it?

Comment: Yes, in any formal system where you can define what it means to run a program in the first place -- plus some very mild conditions to ensure that you can formalize manipulation of programs texts in a meaningful way. There is no metamathematics involved.

Answer (score 3):

It means the former: there is no program $e$ that computes the characteristic function of the set $K = \{ i : \text{program } i \text{ halts on input } i\}$. Undecidablity has nothing to do with *provable* computability, it it just about actual computability.